# Add #ajax callback to an entity_autocomplete field

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I have an entity_autocomplete field in a form.

```
$element['content'] = array(
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#title' => t('Content'),
  '#title_display' => 'hidden',
  '#default_value' => $content_default,
  '#selection_handler' => 'default', 
  '#selection_settings' => array(
    'target_bundles' => $selected_bundles,
  ),
  '#prefix' => '<div class="container-inline">'
);
```

I would like to add an #ajax callback to run after someone has selected a piece of content from the autocomplete drop-down, but I can't seem to find out how to attach it.

I have tried as follows which works for select boxes.

```
   $element['content']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'Drupal\MODULE\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\WIDGET::METHOD',
      'wrapper' => $id,
      'method' => 'replace',
      'progress' => array(
        'type' => 'throbber',
        'message' => "shuffling",
      ),
    );
```

However, it does not fire. Is it possible to do what i need?

It actually fires if you tab out of the field, but I need it to fire after a selection is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 8 (and Drupal 7) provides jQuery autocomplete event generation without any custom code.

Drupal 8 uses the jQuery UI [autocomplete widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete). The `autocompleteclose` event is the jQuery UI event most similar to the D7 `autocompleteSelect` event. In D8 the jQuery UI `autocompleteselect` event will also be also triggered but an Ajax callback on it will not receive updated form state values. `autocompleteclose` callbacks are provided with updated form state values, which is usually what you want.

(In Drupal 7, the `autocompleteSelect` event was added in Drupal issue [#365241](https://www.drupal.org/node/365241).)

In your case, you would assign this as follows:

```
$element['content']['#ajax']['event'] = 'autocompleteclose';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the behavior with

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'event' => 'change',
```

This can be any javascript event. The default for a select is on 'change', for a normal field this is on 'blur'. But you can try any other event.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 0):

As 4k4 mentioned the event can be changed via the #ajax property however there is no event in Drupal that signifies that an autocomplete has just had a selection so the event needs to be added. Taken from [What's the event triggered after an autocomplete has run and how to retrieve the value selected](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/138625/whats-the-event-triggered-after-an-autocomplete-has-run-and-how-to-retrieve-the)

Add the event trigger

```
jQuery(event.target).trigger('autocomplete-select');
```

as follows

```
Drupal.autocomplete.options.select =  function selectHandler(event, ui) {
    var terms = Drupal.autocomplete.splitValues(event.target.value);
    // Remove the current input.
    terms.pop();
    // Add the selected item.
    if (ui.item.value.search(',') > 0) {
        terms.push('"' + ui.item.value + '"');
    }
    else {
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
    }
    event.target.value = terms.join(', ');
    jQuery(event.target).trigger('autocomplete-select');
    // Return false to tell jQuery UI that we've filled in the value already.
    return false;
}
```

Then the #ajax property can be set to listen to this event.

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'event' => 'autocomplete-select',
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. See my answer to a similar question here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/228150/2272

Comment: Are you saying that you can just set

    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'autocompleteSelect',

If there is a better way can you add it as an answer instead of just saying this one is wrong?

Comment: I posted a link in a comment rather than duplicate my answer from another question. As the link I posted states, in Drupal 8 the correct event is 'autocompleteclose'. The 'autocompleteselect' event is also triggered but has some problems. Did you read the link?

Comment: So you are saying that

'#ajax' => array(
  'event' => 'autocompleteclose',

Is the correct answer and works?

Comment: Yes it works. You might also upvote my answer when you find it works for you.

Comment: You haven't provided an answer to accept, if you present it as an actuall answer i will retract the existing accepted answer and use yours instead, thanks for your help.

Comment: None of the ideas here have worked for me. Will post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a date field on an Event entity. I have a second entity (Request) form with an autocomplete entity reference field to those Events. When i select an event from the autocomplete; I want the Event's date to be used as the default value in the date field on the Request form.

at the top of my custom module:

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
```

in my form_alter I have this:

```
$form['field_my_autocomplete_entityref']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#ajax'] = [
   'callback' => '_mymodule_autofill_date',
   'event' => 'autocompleteclose',
 ];
```

I then add the callback function in my custom module:

```
function _mymodule_autofill_date($form, $form_state) {
  $eid = $form_state->getValue('field_my_autocomplete_entityref')[0]['target_id'];
  $event = Node::load($eid);

  // set Request date fields as same value set in Event
  $start = $event->field_event_date->value;
  $end = $event->field_event_date->end_value;

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-field-event-date-0-value-date', 'val', [$start]));
  $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-field-event-date-0-end-value-date', 'val', [$end]));

  return $response;
}
```