# How we can get the value entered in search API autocomplete field in jQuery?

Tags: 8, javascript

I got a requirement to send the search text to GTM for tracking purpose. I have a field which is from search api autocomplete module. I am not getting the value in jQuery on click of submit button. I tried like below but no success:

```
var search_key = $('.path-frontpage .ui-autocomplete-input').attr('value');
```

Can anybody implemented such thing. Please help

DOM:

```
<input placeholder="Search MyP&amp;O" data-drupal-selector="edit-keywords" data-search-api-autocomplete-search="search" class="form-autocomplete form-text form-control ui-autocomplete-input" data-autocomplete-path="/search_api_autocomplete/search?display=page&amp;&amp;filter=keywords" type="text" id="edit-keywords" name="keywords" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: An obvious thing, but in your selector you've got .path-frontpage which will obviously only work when on the homepage. Are you definitely trying on your homepage?

Comment: Yes @Leigh. i'm trying there only.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var search_key = $('.path-frontpage .ui-autocomplete-input').val();
```

Comment: thanks for responding. But for me its showing empty value. I will post my DOM structure. Please check.